# Angular material build error in node modules

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-material

Since Angular material updated, i have had nothing but errors when trying to build/run my project. these errors all reside in the @angular/material under node modules. angular material version 2.0.0-beta.10 was working just fine and then it was updated and now nothing works.

I have already fixed the error of needing to change the imports and implementations from Md to Mat(for example MdToolbarModule was changed to MatToolbarModule) that fixed the errors that actually appeared in visual studio but now on building all of these errors occur.

```
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts (20,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatMenuItemBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/option/optgroup.d.ts (9,22): Class 'MatOptgroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable' Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatOptgroup'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts (55,22): Class 'MatButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatButton'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts (55,22): Class 'MatButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatButton'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts (55,22): Class 'MatButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple' Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatButton'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts (55,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & (new (...args: any[])...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (33,22): Class 'MatButtonToggleGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatButtonToggleGroup'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (33,51): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatButtonToggleGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (92,22): Class 'MatButtonToggleGroupMultiple' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatButtonToggleGroupMultiple'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (92,59): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatButtonToggleGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts (47,22): Class 'MatCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatCheckbox'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts (47,22): Class 'MatCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatCheckbox'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts (47,22): Class 'MatCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatCheckbox'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts (47,22): Class 'MatCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface 'HasTabIndex'. Property 'tabIndex' is missing in type 'MatCheckbox'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts (47,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => HasTabIndex) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts (38,22): Class 'MatChip' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatChip'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts (38,22): Class 'MatChip' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatChip'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts (38,38): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatChipBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts (24,22): Class 'MatExpansionPanel' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatExpansionPanel'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts (24,48): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatExpansionPanelBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/icon/typings/icon.d.ts (38,22): Class 'MatIcon' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatIcon'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/icon/typings/icon.d.ts (38,38): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MatIconBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts (22,22): Class 'MatList' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatList'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts (22,38): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatListBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts (61,22): Class 'MatListItem' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatListItem'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts (61,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatListItemBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (29,22): Class 'MatListOption' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatListOption'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (29,44): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatListOptionBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (70,22): Class 'MatSelectionList' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatSelectionList'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (70,22): Class 'MatSelectionList' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatSelectionList'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (70,22): Class 'MatSelectionList' incorrectly implements interface 'HasTabIndex'. Property 'tabIndex' is missing in type 'MatSelectionList'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts (70,47): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => HasTabIndex) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & (new (...arg...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts (20,22): Class 'MatMenuItem' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatMenuItem'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/option/optgroup.d.ts (9,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatOptgroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts (23,22): Class 'MatProgressSpinner' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatProgressSpinner'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts (23,49): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MatProgressSpinnerBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts (33,44): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatRadioGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts (137,22): Class 'MatRadioButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatRadioButton'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts (137,22): Class 'MatRadioButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatRadioButton'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts (137,45): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatRadio...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts (73,22): Class 'MatSelect' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatSelect'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts (73,22): Class 'MatSelect' incorrectly implements interface 'HasTabIndex'. Property 'tabIndex' is missing in type 'MatSelect'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts (73,22): Class 'MatSelect' incorrectly implements interface 'MatFormFieldControl<any>'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatSelect'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts (73,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => HasTabIndex) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatSelectBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (27,22): Class 'MatSlideToggle' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatSlideToggle'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (27,22): Class 'MatSlideToggle' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatSlideToggle'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (27,22): Class 'MatSlideToggle' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatSlideToggle'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (27,22): Class 'MatSlideToggle' incorrectly implements interface 'HasTabIndex'. Property 'tabIndex' is missing in type 'MatSlideToggle'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (27,45): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => HasTabIndex) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts (36,22): Class 'MatSlider' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatSlider'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts (36,22): Class 'MatSlider' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatSlider'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts (36,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatSliderBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab.d.ts (17,22): Class 'MatTab' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatTab'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab.d.ts (17,37): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatTabBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-group.d.ts (30,22): Class 'MatTabGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatTabGroup'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-group.d.ts (30,22): Class 'MatTabGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatTabGroup'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-group.d.ts (30,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatTabGr...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-label-wrapper.d.ts (18,22): Class 'MatTabLabelWrapper' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatTabLabelWrapper'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-label-wrapper.d.ts (18,49): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatTabLabelWrapperBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts (31,22): Class 'MatTabHeader' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisableRipple'. Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MatTabHeader'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts (31,43): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MatTabHeaderBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (25,22): Class 'MatTabNav' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatTabNav'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (25,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MatTabNa...' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (61,22): Class 'MatTabLink' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'. Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatTabLink'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (61,41): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatTabLinkBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/typings/toolbar.d.ts (19,22): Class 'MatToolbar' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'. Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatToolbar'.
ERROR in C:/Users/lajos/Source/Repos/Appraiser/SafeAtHome/node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/typings/toolbar.d.ts (19,41): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MatToolbarBase' is not a constructor function type.
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your node_modules folder and doing a fresh npm install?

Comment: yes this was also performed and afterwards the same errors existed. @RoughChop

Answer (score 8):

The issue has been resolved, I needed to update my typescript package to fit the requirements that are needed by Angular/material

Comment: Thanks sir, you really saved me like 10hours of research.

Comment: Can you specify the version that resolved the issue?

Answer (score 3):

update the typescript version using the command

`npm install typescript@latest`

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the angular update guide.  I forgot to click "I use Material" at the top of the guide.  I had to update Material.

```
ng update @angular/material@10
```